# Multiprocessing pool.apply_async eats up memory

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

**Use case:**

1. 2 billion combinations of parameters to be processed with 10 servers(16 cores 128GB RAM)
2. Each server process 200 million combinations using *pool.apply_async()* (Python version 3.7)
3. Keep the total processing time as short as possible

**Problem:**

1. Python eats up all memories and throws errors "*RuntimeError: can't start new thread*" and "*OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory*"

I am thinking of replacing *.apply_async()* method to *.apply()*, but I guess that would have a severe impact on the total processing time by changing a non-blocking pattern to a blocking one.

Could anyone help to find the best solution (consumes least time) for this scenario?

**My code:**

```
exec_log = multiprocessing.Manager().list([0, ''])
lock = multiprocessing.Manager().Lock()
cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=cores)

# Parameters a to j
for a in a_list: # a_list contains 2 elements
    for b in b_list: # b_list contains 2 elements
        for c in c_list: # c_list contains 5 elements
            for d in d_list: # d_list contains 10 elements
                for e in e_list: # e_list contains 10 elements
                    for f in f_list: # f_list contains 5 elements
                        for g in g_list: # g_list contains 20 elements
                            for h in h_list: # h_list contains 10 elements
                                for i in i_list: # i_list contains 10 elements
                                    for j in j_list: # j_list contains 10 elements
                                        pool.apply_async(prestart, (df, start_date, end_date, curr_date, 
                                                                    analysis_period, a, b, c, d, e,
                                                                    f, g, h, i, j, exec_log, lock))
pool.close()
pool.join()
logger.info(exec_log[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *Could anyone help to **find the best solution** (consumes least time) **for this scenario?***

Sure, let's inspect the visible part of the shopping-list:

**1)**
**avoid `Lock()`-handling**, given any form of a `Lock()`-ing remains in place, your wish-to-have parallel-organisation of the code-execution implodes back into a blocking-state re-orchestrated pure-`[SERIAL]` one-after-another ( having all the rest waiting for their turn - whatever number of whatever large RAM-on-steriods servers one puts at work - all wait for their turn, trying most of the time to "grab" the `Lock()` )

**2)**
**avoid any form of using sharing**, given any form of shared resources remains in place, your wish-to-have parallel workflow (again) resorts to waiting for a moment any such shared-resource gets freed from any others' use and may start to get used by this process.

**3)**
avoid any excessive process/memory instantiations ( besides your already experienced crashes into RAM-ceiling these are also prohibitively expensive for HPC-grade parallel problem solutions - both in:

- **`[TIME]`**-domain  <sub>... instantiation add-on overheads ... ~ large amounts of thousands of `[ns]`</sub>  and in
- **`[SPACE]`**-domain  <sub>... new memory allocation requirements get handled by O/S at growing scales at remarkable add-on costs, way above ~ large amounts of thousands of `[ns]`, the worst by falling into virtual-memory memory swapping suffocation ... again, paying an associated `[TIME]`-domain costs for moving data memory-blocks ( in-RAM replicas at costs about ~ 300-350 [ns] for a NUMA-CPU-core non-local RAM destinations + data volume-based I/O-bandwidth driven and free-RAM-channel availability further limited such data transport-latencies. In case of falling into swapping, the O/S orchestrated ( i.e. outside of your domain of control ) swap-flows come at costs ~ 1,000 x ~ 10,000 x worse ... and block by having top priority any other attempts to computate and read/write into RAM during that periods of time, so another reason no one would ever want these to ever happen during computing )</sub>

Using **`multiprocessing.get_all_start_methods()`** will show all the options the localhost O/S can provide for elimination ( small-scale mitigation ) of unwanted excessive RAM-allocations.

Using **`len( os.sched_getaffinity(0) )`** control instead of the `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` used above, will eliminate localhost over-subscribing the number of free-to-use CPU-cores ( also having less copies of "just"-`[CONCURRENT]`-RAM-copies, that have to wait its scheduler-ordered turn, before their RAM/CPU-execution gets turn... ), if O/S affinity-mapping policy restricts user-programs from using all the platforms indicated hardware cores.

---

The "awful" **`for`**-based "outer"-iterator may always get improved, yet the core strategy is more important:

### May refactor the code into a [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system) computing :

A clean and performance focused [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system) computing approach may balance the real-world costs against the net-performance-gains one will enjoy, after spending such costs.

Many "syntax-in-mind" approaches fail to scale well above some **principal** growing-sizes - first, by experiencing a Sin of Eviction from In-CACHE computing into  feeling the real costs-of-RAM ( which were not observed in schoolbook examples and demos ), next come the costs of In-RAM data-flow, for larger and larger data-sizes, last, but not least, come the costs of naive expectations from multiprocessing ( which, depending on O/S and version, may introduce generation add-on costs of allocating many full-python-session-replicas, that may crash the memory-error - as would in the posted case above )

Given 10 servers have 16 cores and 128 GB RAM each, the promising move in concept will test the sizing of the python-proces when computing the **`prestart()`** with data and next spawn not more "workers" inside a server than till they all fit into RAM ( to avoid swapping ), next create a messaging/signaling meta-layer to orchestrate smart parameter-passing of that many jobs across this pool-of-distributed workers, using any of the high-performance, low latency tool, like ZeroMQ or nanomsg are, and design the workflow so as you never pass a single piece of data twice ( as the add-on costs of parameter passing grows worse than O(n), due to system and O/S properties ), so never move a piece of data twice in a performance-motivated system.

---

Following these few simple rules does not come cheap, yet there are no faster ways ( the less they come for free ... )